# Work done by normal force in this case

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

[image]

Here a ball initially moving with velocity v, strikes a spring. Consider the motion only till the spring is fully compressed.

I am confused with the work done by the normal force(as observed in the ground frame) acting between the ball and the spring in this case.

I thought as the spring is doing positive work on the spring in compressing it and negative work on the ball to decrease its kinetic energy, which are equal in magnitude, net work done by it will be 0.

But the solution says work done by the normal force will be equal to the change in kinetic energy of the ball. How?

Can anybody please explain??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work done by the spring *on the ball* is equal to the change in kinetic energy of the ball. And work done *by the ball on the spring* is equal and opposite to the work done by the spring on the ball (by Newton’s Third Law) - and is also equal to the change in potential energy of the spring.

An alternative way to look at this is to consider the ball and spring as one single system. From this point of view the force between the spring and the ball is an internal force, and does no work on the system as a whole. So (as long as there are no losses due to friction etc.) the change in kinetic energy of the ball is balanced by an equal and opposite change in the potential energy stored in the spring.